# How do I turn off backlight of keyboard?

Tags: backlight, keyboard-backlight, xbacklight

I've tried `xset led 3`, `xset led off`, `xbacklight -set 00`,

`sudo find /sys/devices/platform/ -name leds` returns nothing, so I couldn't try that.

`sudo find /sys/devices -name leds` returns `/sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:1c.5/0000\:3f\:00.0/leds`, but `sudo echo '0' > /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:1c.5/0000\:3f\:00.0/leds/phy0-led/brightness` returns permission denied (yes, even with sudo).

`sudo xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Caps_Lock'` returns error

`X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
  Value in failed request:  0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  11`

So, I pretty much just copied and pasted a bunch of solutions from stack overflow, and so far nothing has worked, although, this, I believe should be a very simple thing to do.

I'm on a Lenovo Yoga 720, running ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: FYI: 18.10 is not yet on topic here on Ask Ubuntu - it's still in development.

Comment: About `sudo echo > ...`, see [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82256/4518341) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` to run those `find` commands

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to turn off the backlight

Comment: I wish I had found this before I wasted 30 mins browsing all of Internet. I can't thank you enough stranger in the internet.

Comment: I am looking for an alternative because this isn't working for me due to some reason. I think I was too hasty while pressing Fn + Space. My laptop was rebooting and I was still on the GRUB screen when I started hitting the combination. The backlit is turned ON continuously from then.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings → *Power* → *Power Saving* → *Keyboard Brightness*.